# MATLAB hist3: Setting number of bins, centers, and edges with custom widths

Tags: matlab, histogram

I'm trying to use the following line

```
hist3(dat, 'Nbins', [nbinsx nbinsy], 'Ctrs', [bincenterx bincentery], ...
  'Edges', {xbounds,ybounds});
```

to yield a histogram that fits the following: my detector is an 8 x 8 grid of pixels, each with some width, and their centers are separated by the same distance. dat contains the data for all detected events as calculated to some point on each of the pixels, hence why I need a large number of bins.

For some reason, the error I'm getting using that line is "Ambiguous specification of bins."

Is there an alternate method? Or am I making a small, silly mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You are giving too many arguments to the `hist3` function. You can either specify the number of bins, or the bin centers, or the bin edges, but not all of them together.

Here is a quick example to show the difference between the three methods:

```
dat = rand(100,2);

figure(1)
hist3(dat, 'Nbins', [5,10]);

figure(2)
centers = {(0.1:0.2:0.9),(0.05:0.1:0.95)};
hist3(dat, 'Ctrs', centers);

figure(3)
edges = {(0:0.2:1),(0:0.1:1)}; 
hist3(dat, 'Edges', edges);
```

Note that you have to supply the centers or the edges inside a cell-array, because the vectors can have different lengths.

If you compare the three plots, you will notice subtle differences between them. For example, the third plot contains (surprisingly, I would say!) an additional row and an additional column of empty bins for `1 <= x < 1.2` and `1 <= y < 1.2`. The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html) <s>mentions something like this, but I still find it surprising...</s> doesn't mention this, the `hist3` function creates an extra edge at each high end. (This looks like one of those "features" that was put in to be backwards compatible with older, buggy software.)

Also, the first plot seems to use slightly different binning. Indeed, when you look around line 164 of the `hist3` function (`edit hist3`), you can see that when the number of bins are specified, `hist3` uses the min and max values and evenly distributes the bins in between. This is not a huge change, but here and there an event ends up in a bin to the left or to the right.

[image: hist3 plot with specifying number of bins]

[image: hist3 plot with specifying centers]

[image: hist3 plot with specifying edges]

Comment: `hist3` behaves just like `hist`. The documentation does mention the extra bins, just not explicitly: Rows of `X` that fall on the upper edges of the grid, `edges{1}(end)` or `edges{2}(end)`, are counted in the (`I`,`j`)th or (`i`,`J`)th bins, where `I` and `J` are the lengths of `edges{1}` and `edges{2}`. In your example `I` and `J` are 6. Binning sucks, which it probably what many statisticians despise histograms.